# How to add image to navbar-brand in ASP.NET MVC 5 RAZOR

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

i am trying asp.net mvc these days but stuck in beginning phase. I want to place image in place of application name with title and alt tag. please help me.

Thank you

```
<div class="navbar-header pull-left">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/accomodator-mini.png" title="title" alt="additional title" /></a>
</div>
```

how to do above in this way:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

i am confused how to show image in the place of Application name

Comment: And it's not working?

Comment: @TheBokiya . hello what do you mean? i don't understand what you mean.. Razor syntax are like Html.ActionLink

Comment: No that's just C#. This is Razor syntax http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/razor_syntax.asp

Comment: @TheBokiya. ya i know razor starts with email sign but in comment its not allowed. thanks for the link

Comment: I'm still not quite sure what you're looking for but please see my answer below

Comment: @TheBokiya.  similar to your answer but i don't want to get image from css because the image is not displaying properly(full).. i want get this <div class="navbar-header pull-left">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"><img src="img/accomodator-mini.png" title="title" alt="additional title" /></a>
</div>

Comment: want to use <img src="img/accomodator-mini.png" title="title" alt="additional title" />

Comment: Please take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/10094231/3421070

Answer (score 15):

**1 option:**
You can do everything in css:

```
.navbar-brand{
    background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150) no-repeat;
    background-size: 40px 40px;
    height:40px;
    margin:5px;
    width:40px;
}
```

**[JsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/3r27P/1/)** - in this example image is 350x150 px. And using `background-size` property you can adjust the image size.

**2 option:**

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="navbar-brand">
    <img src="img/accomodator-mini.png" title="title" alt="additional title" />
</a>
```

**3 option:**
 [Define your own helper](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs).

Comment: You're missing the .Action on @Url.

Answer (score 8):

Its simple. In MVC-5, this works.

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="navbar-brand">
  <img src="~/Images/logo.png" title="title" alt="additional title" />
</a>
```

And make sure your logo is placed in the correct folder.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
```

Then in the css, have this:

```
.navbar-brand {
    background-image: url(img/accomodator-mini.png);
}
```

Comment: This works but the string "Application name" is still rendered.

Comment: The first argument for ActionLink is just a link text to display. It should be fairly simple. You might need to check your class name and your image path.

Answer (score 1):

Open your MVC application folder, create a folder called 'images' next to all other folders (Model, View, Controller,...) put your logo.jpg inside the folder `images`. Then open View/Home/index.cshtml in your Visual Studio editor and place the following line of html code inside the top `<div>`:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="Games Logo" ALIGN="right" />
    <h1>Computer Games Library</h1>
    <p class="lead">Programmer: Marzieh Farahani</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Robin requested help with replacing the text " I want to place image in place of application name with title and alt tag." with an image.